# How to unbind mousemove function

Tags: javascript, jquery

When a use moves their mouse on a webpage, I want to track that. Then I want to unbind that listener so that mousemove no longer gets tracked. How can I do that? The code below does not seem to work.

```
var clearIdleInterval = function () {
                console.dir('unbind');
                clearInterval(this.idleInterval);
                $(document).unbind('mousemove', clearIdleInterval.bind(this));
                $(document).unbind('keypress', clearIdleInterval.bind(this));
            };
$(document).bind('mousemove', clearIdleInterval.bind(this));
$(document).bind('keypress', clearIdleInterval.bind(this));
```

Comment: `$(document ).unbind( "mousemove" );` ??

Comment: One thing: `.off()` http://api.jquery.com/off/

Comment: `.bind` creates a _new_ function every time. To unbind you need to pass the _same_ function, if you’re going to pass any function.

Comment: Is it possible to off a specific listener? Life if I have multiple mousemove listeners on the page, how can I off only one of them?

Comment: @Jasmine did you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49807064/6804958) answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.unbind()` to unbind events. As shown below.

Note: If you want to unbind  `mousemove` event for specific elements, and avoid to affect other handlers, you can do that too. For example

`$( "#foo" ).unbind( "mousemove.myEvents" );`

It is documented really well [here](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)

Hope that was helpful.

```js
$(document).bind('mousemove', function(e){
   $(".test").html(`${e.clientX} , ${e.clientY}`)
});

function unBind(){
$(document).unbind( "mousemove" );
}
```

```css
.test{
 text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
line-height: 90px; 
   height : 200px;
   width : 200px;
   border : solid;
   margin-top : 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button onclick="unBind()">Un Bind</button>


<div class="test"></div>
```

Comment: As of jQuery 3.0, .unbind() has been deprecated. It was superseded by the .off() method since jQuery 1.7, so its use was already discouraged.